# Does this statement about Smartas have scriptural authority?

Tags: caste-system, brahmins, smarta

A book by [Agehananda Bharati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agehananda_Bharati) contains a [statement on Smartas](https://archive.org/stream/112798314TheLightAtTheCentreContextAndPretextOfModernMysticismAgehanandaBharati/112798314-The-Light-at-the-Centre-Context-and-Pretext-of-Modern-Mysticism-Agehananda-Bharati_djvu.txt):

> The Smarta-brahmins of the Tamil. Telugu. and Malayalam speaking 
>   areas of the Dravidian South of India are no doubt the highest caste by 
>   consensus and acclaim; ideologically, they are followers of Samkaracarya ■ they worship all Vedic gods on the ritualistic side, but Siva is their tutelary deity and the monistic Advaita philosophy provides their main 
>   ideological framework.

Is it factual about their practices and does the statement about their status have any scriptural basis?

Comment: Which part of the quote are you asking about?  And regardless of which part of the quote you’re asking about, I don’t see how scripture would say anything about it

Comment: Why would scripture talk about a sect/group who follow Adi Shankaracharya's ideology formed after 8th century?

Comment: It is very unlikely that scriptures would talk about a sect of brahmins.

Comment: Agehananda Bharati IS scripture, since he was a Dashanami Sanyasi.@Lazy Lubber